# How to eliminate the margin between the fixed bottom menu and the bottom of window?

Tags: html, css

The HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #top-menu {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 10;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color:rgba(255,255,0,0.5); 
        }

        #top-menu li {
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
        }

        #top-menu a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px 25px 5px 25px;
            width: 4em;
            text-align: center;
            -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
            -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
            transition: .5s all ease-out;
            border-bottom: 3px solid cyan;
            color: #aaa;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #top-menu a:hover {
            color: #000;
        }

        #top-menu li.active a {
            border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
            color: red;
        }

        #foo {
            margin-top: 400px;
        }

        #bar {
            margin-top: 400px;
        }

        #baz {
            margin-top: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="top-menu">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Top</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#baz">Baz</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <h2 id="foo">Foo</h2>
    <h2 id="bar">Bar</h2>
    <h2 id="baz">Baz</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

When I test it in Firefox 42, there is some margin between the fixed bottom menu and the bottom of window.

**How to eliminate the margin between the fixed bottom menu and the bottom of window ?**

[image: margin···]

Comment: Add rule `ul { margin: 0 }` to your CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `ul` element has a default top/bottom `margin`.

In this instance, either add `margin: 0` to the `#top-menu` element, or just reset the default margin(s) for all `ul` elements using a CSS reset.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tuq0zh76/)

```
#top-menu {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0; /* Added */
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```